# Android Activity Crash when Using Achartengine + Asynctask

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

can someone help me..
i have a problem the log shows as below
LOG

```
03-22 16:22:04.804: E/AndroidRuntime(5329): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 16:22:04.804: E/AndroidRuntime(5329): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start    activity ComponentInfo{com.thesis.awsapp/com.thesis.awsapp.Graph}:   java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 16:22:04.804: E/AndroidRuntime(5329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
03-22 16:22:04.804: E/AndroidRuntime(5329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
03-22 16:22:04.804: E/AndroidRuntime(5329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-22 16:22:04.804: E/AndroidRuntime(5329):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
03-22 16:22:04.804: E/AndroidRuntime(5329):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-22 16:22:04.804: E/AndroidRuntime(5329):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-22 16:22:04.804: E/AndroidRuntime(5329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-22 16:22:04.804: E/AndroidRuntime(5329):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 16:22:04.804: E/AndroidRuntime(5329):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-22 16:22:04.804: E/AndroidRuntime(5329):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
03-22 16:22:04.804: E/AndroidRuntime(5329):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
03-22 16:22:04.804: E/AndroidRuntime(5329):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-22 16:22:04.804: E/AndroidRuntime(5329): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 16:22:04.804: E/AndroidRuntime(5329):     at com.thesis.awsapp.Graph.OpenChart(Graph.java:186)
03-22 16:22:04.804: E/AndroidRuntime(5329):     at com.thesis.awsapp.Graph.onCreate(Graph.java:54)
03-22 16:22:04.804: E/AndroidRuntime(5329):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-22 16:22:04.804: E/AndroidRuntime(5329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
03-22 16:22:04.804: E/AndroidRuntime(5329):     ... 11 more
03-22 16:22:04.820: E/liblog(1486): failed to call dumpstate
 03-22 16:22:04.828: E/(1486): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

this is the code that i used

CODE:

```
package com.thesis.awsapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;

 import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
 import org.achartengine.GraphicalView;
import org.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;
import org.achartengine.model.SeriesSelection;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.model.XYSeries;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;
 import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
 import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Graph extends Activity {

private GraphicalView mChart;
String[] mMonth;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.graph_layout);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String Query = intent.getExtras().getString("Query");

    getDataa mDoPOST = new getDataa(Graph.this, Query);
    mDoPOST.execute("");
    OpenChart();

}

public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    this.finish();
}

public class getDataa extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

    String strNameToSearch = "";
    ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<String> Date = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Result data

    Exception exception = null;

    getDataa(Context context, String nameToSearch) {

        strNameToSearch = nameToSearch;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        try {

            // Setup the parameters
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("QUERY",
                    strNameToSearch));
            // Add more parameters as necessary

            // Create the HTTP request
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

            // Setup timeouts
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                    15000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://210.14.5.179/aws/getLocal2.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            // Create a JSON object from the request response

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("tblStations");



            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject curr = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                list.add(Double.parseDouble(curr.getString("temperature")));
                Date.add(curr.getString("Time"));
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ClientServerDemo", "Error:", e);
            exception = e;
        }

        return Date;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> Date) {
        mMonth =Date.toArray(new String[Date.size()]);

    }
}

// /////////////////////////////////////

private void OpenChart() {
    // Define the number of elements you want in the chart.
    int z[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

    int x[] = { 10, 18, 32, 21, 48, 60, 53, 80 };

    // Create XY Series for X Series.
    XYSeries xSeries = new XYSeries("X Series");

    // Adding data to the X Series.
    for (int i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
        xSeries.add(z[i], x[i]);

    }

    // Create a Dataset to hold the XSeries.

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

    // Add X series to the Dataset.
    dataset.addSeries(xSeries);

    // Create XYSeriesRenderer to customize XSeries

    XYSeriesRenderer Xrenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    Xrenderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    Xrenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.DIAMOND);
    Xrenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    Xrenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    Xrenderer.setFillPoints(true);

    // Create XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    mRenderer.setChartTitle("X Vs Y Chart");
    mRenderer.setXTitle("X Values");
    mRenderer.setYTitle("Y Values");
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(false);

    mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);

    mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, mMonth[i]);
    }

    // Adding the XSeriesRenderer to the MultipleRenderer.
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(Xrenderer);

    LinearLayout chart_container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Chart_layout);

    // Creating an intent to plot line chart using dataset and
    // multipleRenderer

    mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getLineChartView(
            getBaseContext(), dataset, mRenderer);

    // Adding click event to the Line Chart.

    mChart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            SeriesSelection series_selection = mChart
                    .getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();

            if (series_selection != null) {
                int series_index = series_selection.getSeriesIndex();

                String select_series = "X Series";
                if (series_index == 0) {
                    select_series = "X Series";
                } else {
                    select_series = "Y Series";
                }

                String month = mMonth[(int) series_selection.getXValue()];

                int amount = (int) series_selection.getValue();

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        select_series + "in" + month + ":" + amount,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

    // Add the graphical view mChart object into the Linear layout .
    chart_container.addView(mChart);

}
 }
```

can someone suggest something?.. i am trying to graph the data from webserver.
in this code i am tring to get the time and make it as X axis label.

and also can someone give me tips on how to graph the data from webserver?

thank you very much

THIS IS MY XML FILE

XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Chart_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does your `graph_layout` really have `Chart_Layout`? It seems that either `chart_container` or `mChart` is `null`

Comment: looks like `chart_container` is null. Please show XML

Comment: `mMonth` array is null

Comment: @laalto that is the problem my Asynctask should get fill the mMonth with data.. but it seems it doesnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're accessing the `mMonth` array in `OpenChart()` but you only initialize it in your async task `onPostExecute()` which takes place much later.

Either initialize `mMonth` with reasonable defaults, skip the parts where you need `mMonth` or postpone the `OpenChart()` altogether until the data is available.

Comment: thanks, i put the OpenChart() on the onPostExecute()

Comment: i do have another question, how can i apply the list array in the asynctask as values for my graph? any suggestions please.. thanks